Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/frontend/build/index.html'
Good morning colleagues. Could you please help me?
My Whaticket was working normally. I installed a Typebot on the same IP and with other notes on my domain.
When opening this TypBot, it opened with the same FRONT as the previously installed whaticket.
Then:
I REINSTALLED the VPS, started from scratch. First installing TypeBot, which opened and worked normally.
When I reinstall Whaticket the following error appears:
"Future versions of Certbot will automatically configure the webserver so that all requests redirect to secure HTTPS access. You can control this behavior and disable this warning with the –redirect and –no-redirect flags."
In the frontend the error appears:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat ‘/home/xxx /xxx /frontend/build/index.html’
In other words, you can't find the index.html file inside the build folder!!
I went into the /frontend/build/ folder and verified that there was no index.html file
*I believe it ended up in the old /home/xxx /xxx /frontend/build/old/index.html folder (as there is an index.html file there)
I copied the index.html file from the /old folder and pasted it into the build folder, but when I go to Build /Front/build (npm run build) another error appears:
enter image description here
And the index.html file disappears again from the /build folder
What do I do?
Could anyone please help me???
Install a Whaticket file
